# Filling textfields with text when a switch is activated

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to fill a textfield with text that I have stored in a NSUserDefaults variable from one of my other pages when I turn on a switch. When I turn the switch on I get an error message of "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Here is the code that I have that gives me the error. gamesListText is the NSUserDefaults variable that I have already data in.

```
@IBAction func switchActivated(sender: AnyObject) {

    if switch.on {
        gameSearchLabel.text = gameListText
    }
}
```

I have looked at other people who get this error but none of them really apply to my particular situation and they are pretty dated questions.

Comment: @IBOutlet var preferenceSwitch: UISwitch!

Comment: I just made a basic outlet for my switch @IBOutlet var preferenceSwitch: UISwitch!. My gamesListText is a global string var gamesListText = "". In my viewDidLoad function I then set gamesListText = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("gamesListText") as! String. After I set gamesListText I attach it to a textfield so that it is equal to whatever I type in the textfield and finally it is updated every time I press my save button.

Comment: @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {   gamesListText = gamesListTextField.text NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gamesListText, forKey: "gamesListText") }

Comment: Just delete your IBOutlet. You can use the sender from the IBAction

Comment: I tried that it gives an error of AnyObject does not have a member of 'on'

Comment: func switchActivated(sender: UISwitch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func switchActivated(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on {
        gameSearchLabel.text = gameListText
    }
}
```

at your viewDidLoad

```
gamesListText = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("gamesListText") ?? ""
```

Comment: This solved the issue thanks for the help Leo and everyone thanks for the comments much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Rename your outlet to something other than `switch`. Swift thinks you're trying to define a [`switch` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html).

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchOutlet: UISwitch!
@IBAction func switchAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if switchOutlet.on {
        println("switch is ON")
    }
    else {
        println("switch is OFF")
    }
}
```

Also, you should be using `stringForKey` instead of `objectForKey` when setting/getting your `NSUserDefaults` because you are setting/getting a `String` type.